# Click button on specific line

Tags: html, button, click, applescript

```
<input id="btnplus" type="button" onclick="Thisone(this,0)" name="btnplus" value="plus"></input
<input id="btnplus" type="button" onclick="Thisone(this,1)" name="btnplus" value="plus"></input
```

I have a table where i need to click a specific button. The only way to identify which button, I need to do a search for the "Thisone(this,**0**)" with the value 0, 1, 2, etc...
How can I make sure that when I order to click, it will click the button (btnplus) on the same line ? All lines have the same button name.

thanks

Comment: U have a value `this` so thats mean this button, but it depends how u have coded the script for that..

Comment: it's from a web page that i didn't design. Anything I should be looking for specifically ? I can't find any other reference to "this" anywhere.

Comment: I gonna help u with it, i just need what u really want.. I want to click on the button and run script for the same button.. and what should do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a JavaScript as follows

```
<script>
   function Thisone(param1,param2){
   alert(param2);
}
</script>
```

Then the value of the param2 will be displayed when you click on the button.

Comment: Dinidu, thanks for your help. Sorry but I am brand new to this. I have been able to tweak everything to what I needed, but that is the last thing I need to figure out. How do I run a JavaScript on a specific page ?

Comment: just add my code in the`header section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
do JavaScript "Thisone(this, 0)" in document 1 of window 1
end tell
```

I just have to change the 0 to a variable.
Problem solved.